# How set sub directories/folders in public_html 403 forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm using Codeigniter with Hostgator shared hosting.

How to set sub directories/folders in public_html 403 forbidden? but the files in this folders is accessable.

example:

> /public_html/this_forlder_forbidden/this-file-not-forbidden.ext

example 1

> /public_html/js/jquery.js
>
> /public_html/css/style.css

below is my .htaccess file codes in /public_html/ directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?mydomain\.com(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{CORS}e" env=CORS
Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

Comment: You probably just want `Options -Indexes`. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the directories that are off limits to visit from a browser:
place a .htaccess file containing:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

But if possible, move those directories outside the document root

**Addendum**
I forgot: for Apache 2.4 the syntax is

```
Require all denied
```

instead of the 2 lines for older Apache versions

Comment: i'll try. where to put this 2 lines of code? at the end of my current .htaccess codes?

Comment: typically only those two lines. You place them in a .htaccess file in the directory where you want no one to go. So rewriterule would not be in place there any way

Comment: thanks a lot @Ivo P , easy solution, work like charm!

Answer (score 0):

**Go to Codeigniter/application folder

copy index.html

and paste it in /public_html**
when someone tries to open /public_html then index.html trigger automatically.
index.html show "Directory access is forbidden."

Comment: some other way.... because when file will get access i.e /js/jquery.js then it show... i want it accessible only in html pages or according to requirement not the direct access

Comment: do you mean moved index.html file to public_html dir?

Comment: i've try it. result is my index/homepage (baseurl.com) is forbidden. but folder in public_html still available for public (ex: baseurl.com/js/ or baseurl.com/css/)

Comment: No, just copy and paste.
and also same thing for **.htaccess** . but .htaccess block all file also

Comment: I've do it and the result still same like i've mention in reply. also in my /public_html/ already have .htaccess, then in my /application/ didn't have .htaccess @KundanPrasad

Comment: if you put .htaccess in /public_html/ then you _can't aceess_ any file of /public_html/ folder except PHP script.
to access file content use PHP function like
**$content=file_get_contents("/public_html/filename.ext");** @KamarulAnuar

Comment: Yes @KundanPrasad my .htacess already in /public_html/ but the directories in it (such /js/ and /css/) not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe better approach for what you want. Move `application` and `system` directories outside `public_html` and after that just set new paths to those directories in `public_html/index.php` file that should be:

```
$system_path = '../system'; // line 93
```

and

```
$application_folder = '../application'; // line 110
```